# MJPEG in Chrome mobile

Tags: html, google-chrome, mjpeg

I have a stream from IP-Camera. It works great in safari and adequately in opera mini, but on chrome i recive nothing or if directly open stream i get this:

[image]

To display i use this code

```
<input width="320" type="image" height="240" border="0" id="Сamera" src="url">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be experiencing Chrome [Issue 135337](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135337), in which MJPEG images fetched directly fail to animate.

Reportedly, it's fixed in version 22. So, you can either upgrade to that version or change your code to embed the image in an HTML page. E.g., the following works in Chrome 21 (even if nothing's going on, the timestamp should still increment):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>
      Test MJPEG Animation
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>
      Test MJPEG Animation
    </h2>
    <img src="http://193.40.245.181/mjpg/video.mjpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

However, simply pointing the browser at `http://193.40.245.181/mjpg/video.mjpg` shows only the first frame.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this [node.js proxy](https://github.com/wilhelmbot/Paparazzo.js). It parses m-jpeg streams and delivers images to all browsers.

[Cross-browser solution for displaying MJPEG stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269376/cross-browser-solution-for-displaying-mjpeg-stream/12966492#12966492)

Comment: As i understood, you author of this? If it possible, can you please give me compiled js code? And is it tested on chrome mobile?

Comment: @rodowi I am actually undergoing a project with some IP cams, if you would contact me maybe we can discuss further