# Check motion jpeg stream

Tags: javascript, jquery, mjpeg

Is there any way to check if a [Motion JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG) stream is on/working/sending images using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: What do you want to check for? Just display? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269376/cross-browser-solution-for-displaying-mjpeg-stream

Comment: you can check if it gets loaded or not... Don't think there are much other events to listen to...  `$output = $('<img id="webcam">').attr('src', src).load(function(){alert('ok')}).error(function(){alert('error')});`

Comment: @VDP ReferenceError: src is not defined

Comment: lol! you have to define it `var src = 'your url'` also you have to append the `$output` to the dom if you want to see it :) This snippet is creating a new img tag adding a src and adding an onload and onerror callback that's all :)

Comment: @VDP image is already streaming - i only need to check if it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Check image bytes checksum changed periodically. Sure it is not the best solution, but it may help.

```
<img id="video" src="http://192.168.1.60:81/stream" />

<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(checkStream, 1000);

function getImageData() {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var img = document.getElementById('video');
    c.width = img.width;
    c.height = img.height;
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
}

var checkSum = null;

function checkStream() {
    var data = getImageData();
    var newCheckSum = calcChecksum(data.data);
    if (checkSum == null) {
        checkSum = newCheckSum;
    } else {
        if (checkSum == newCheckSum) {
            alert('stall');
        } else {
            checkSum = newCheckSum;
        }
    }
}

function calcChecksum(bytes) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var index = 0; index < bytes.length; index++) {
        sum ^= bytes[index];
    }
    return sum;
}
```