# jquery check if stream loaded from ip every 500ms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if I have a connection to my webcam in the same network.
At the moment I include it with this js code:

```
document.write('<IMG id="camera" width="' + view_w + '" height="' + view_h + '" SRC="http://192.168.1.195/GetData.cgi?CH=1"');
```

It works well! Now I turned off the router. After a few second is the stream away. 
Now I want to check it every 500ms. When I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#camera').load(function(){
        alert("loaded");
    });

    $('#camera').error(function(){
        alert("not loaded");
    });
});
```

It works well, and I get an alert window on the screen (both events works!).

Now I placed this into a `intervall`, but it don't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#camera').load(function(){
            alert("loaded");
        });

        $('#camera').error(function(){
            alert("not loaded");
        });
    }, 500);
});
```

What is the problem with the last code snippet?

Comment: So you want to check if the stream is available every 500ms?

Comment: A stream is not a finite picture that triggers the load event. The load event is triggered when the image finishes loading. You cannot interrogate the state of the stream from an image. Also NEVER alert in an interval loop

Comment: The interval will only fire the first time after the first 500ms, by then your img is probably loaded

Comment: Yes, I want to check every 500ms if the stream is available. But the event will fire, if it can't be loaded anymore?

Comment: The image is loaded once, so it either is loaded or there's an error. Unless you are "refreshing" (let's say, changing the url of the image - maybe a random number in the query string) it will only happen once.

Comment: @MarioCesar thanks for the answer! How can  I check something like this then? Because I dont want to add every 500ms the `IP Address` to the `src` element. Because I thought the correct way is to check if its loaded corretly then do nothing, and if an error occurs update the `src` element. (If I updata the `src` every 500ms without checking, I can turn the router off then the image is away and after turn the router on, the stream will displayed)

Comment: Maybe you can do an AJAX call to your webcam on the interval, instead of do it on load.

Comment: @AdrianMenendez yeha I will try it! Maybe it works.

Comment: Related, yet unanswered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313309/check-motion-jpeg-stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var imgSrc = 'http://192.168.1.195/GetData.cgi?CH=1';

$('#camera').load(function(){
    alert("loaded");
    createTimeout();        
});

$('#camera').error(function(){
    alert("not loaded");
    createTimeout();
});


function changeImgSrc(){
    $('#camera').attr('source', imgSrc + '&_random=' + new Date().getTime());
};

function createTimeout(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        changeImgSrc();
    }, 500)
};

//first execution
changeImgSrc();      
});
```

I didn't try this code.

Comment: If it worked, the alert would block further processing until dismissed. Instead show something in a div.

Comment: Ok, i tried it, but it didn't worked. After turning the router on I have to reload the page first to see the stream. But thanks! :)

Comment: Yes, the alert would block the process, but I assume the alert is just for debugging purpose.

Comment: @MyNewName have you tried some console logs to test the function calls?

Comment: A stream will never retrigger a load handler

Comment: @MarioCesar no... Normally I dont make website, but for this project... . I will search for a tutorial.