# Online images streaming (MJPEG) not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, internet-explorer-11

Actually I am getting continuous images which is actually a video from a link. Now when I'm going to display it as:

```
<img src="http://192.168.2.50:8080/livemjpeg" title="Live Streaming" alt="Live Streaming"/>
```

It gives no issue in Chrome & Firefox but doesn't play well in IE 11. Please help!

Comment: What Foaster said in their answer, even Wikipedia could have told you already: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#Client_software

Answer (score 3):

IE doesn't support MJPEG by default, you either need a Plugin in your Browser or some kind of applet on the website.

[SO: Cross-browser solution for displaying MJPEG stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269376/cross-browser-solution-for-displaying-mjpeg-stream)