# Is there any way to display MJPEG video stream in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, video-streaming, internet-explorer-11, mjpeg

I'm developing a web application with ASP.NET for viewing live feed from IP camera and the camera returns MJPEG video to the client side. This application need to be cross browser friendly including IE. But IE does not support MJPEG to be played using `<img>` tag.

I already tried to use js library from https://github.com/clipchamp/jquery-clipchamp-mjpeg-player-plugin but stuck with CORS policy issue and I have no control on the server side of the video host.

This is the code which is working in Chrome and Firefox but doesn't seems to work in IE.

`<img src="http://192.168.0.38:8601/Interface/Cameras/GetJPEGStream?Camera=02"/>`

Is there any workaround to display live MJPEG video in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IE does not support MJPEG format. This can be the possible reason that your code is not working for Internet Explorer.

As a work around you can try to use JAVA Applet for cross browser support. Which may help to solve your issue.

References:

(1) [Online images streaming (MJPEG) not working in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959830/online-images-streaming-mjpeg-not-working-in-ie-11)

(2) [Cross-browser solution for displaying MJPEG stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269376/cross-browser-solution-for-displaying-mjpeg-stream)

(3) [README File for Cambozola V0.936](http://www.charliemouse.com/code/cambozola/)