# VB.net viewing IP CAM using WebBroswer

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to view a IP CAM and displaying it in a WebBroswer, but i keep geting an error. [image]
Here is the code im using.

```
Dim z As String = "http://ip_address/mjpeg?res=half&x0=0&y0=0&x1=1600&y1=1200&quality=12&doublescan=0&sei=on%20HTTP/1.1\r\n%20Host:%20ip_address\r\n\r\n"
WebBrowser1.Navigate(z)
```

Comment: Please remember to format the code in your question. The simplest way to do so is by inserting four spaces at the beginning of each code line (for more see [How to format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). -- As for your problem, try changing the [browser emulation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793687/Configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-Internet-Expl) to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: `WebBrowser` basically is *Internet Explorer* and IE [does not support MJPEG streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#Client_software) on its own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Explorer is unfortunately the base for the web browser component in win forms. In turn by default it will not understand the MJPEG file format so will ask you to download the file.

Try using chromium (open source chrome) as it should handle this file format.

https://thechriskent.com/2014/08/18/embedded-chromium-in-winforms/

Alternatively you could look at the options here: [Cross-browser solution for displaying MJPEG stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269376/cross-browser-solution-for-displaying-mjpeg-stream) as you maybe able to wrap it in another way